# Typed: Accidentally entered 'cat' in git bash and I cant exit

Tags: git-bash

[image]

I had tried everything to close this one yet I fail. please lend me some hands, I'm new to git bash and currently studying it

Comment: Try Ctrl+D or Ctrl+Z or Ctrl+C, but bear in mind that this question is tutorial-level, you would be best to actually find the manual or help file on cat instead of posting this type of question. Additionally, questions about general programs and software is best suited for [SU], but again, this question here is tutorial-level, you should not post this level question on either site.

Comment: sorry if i had to, im so lost and doesn't really had an idea about this environment.. I tried ur solution and nothing works.. please give me other solution

Comment: In Unix cat command expects a file name - the content of which will be  displayed on the console; try entering a string and press Enter

Comment: Of course one can look at a tutorial to get up to speed with using git bash https://openhatch.org/missions/windows-setup/understand-prompt

Comment: sorry.. lasse V karlsen answer is already correct..
my git bash window doesn't close anymore, maybe because i ended its process via task manager which maybe makes it fail to comply with the commands given.. i'd tried to open a window again and do the same process and use the answer and it works.. thanks @karlsen

Comment: thanks adrian for the info... bookmarked already :)